# cocos2d-x: writing words on screen in multiple lines

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

In `cocos2d-x` when I use CCLABELTTF it writes the words in consecutive order. Is there a class in `cocos2d-x` that gets a place,width, height and a string then inscribe it in that rectangle on the screen and if the string's length is bigger than rectangle's size, breaks it in multiple lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this method of CCLabelTTF class?

```
bool initWithString (const char *string, const char *fontName, float fontSize, const CCSize &dimensions, CCTextAlignment hAlignment, CCVerticalTextAlignment vAlignment)
```